# Corona code signing not working

Tags: iphone, coronasdk

i am using the trial edition of corona and when i try to run the app i made on my iPhone it gives me the following errors.

warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)

Executable=/Users/alfredjunco/untitled folder 2/Bridge.app/Bridge
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: using Apple CA for profile evaluation

how do i fix this

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't a registered iOS developer, you need to pay the $100 fee, which you can do [here](http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/).  If you are, then you need to get a certificate for your app, which you can read more about [here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action).